# Waffle 3.3.0 does not work with Tomcat 10.1.18

Tags: tomcat10, waffle

With Tomcat 10.1.18: If I try to browse a web-page which is configured with waffle 3.3.0 I get an error-message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void waffle.util.AuthorizationHeader.(jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)'
waffle.apache.NegotiateAuthenticator.authenticate(NegotiateAuthenticator.java:78)
waffle.apache.NegotiateAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(NegotiateAuthenticator.java:196)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
```

There seems to be a conflict regarding the parameter of the constructor in waffle.util.AuthorizationHeader. It uses javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, but the caller probably uses jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest. Could you please take a look at it? Thank you.

Display the page without Error-Message

Comment: You'll either need a version of waffle that depends on [servlet-spec 6, or use Tomcat 9](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html). Slight chance that tomcat's automatic conversion could help you.